# Wordpress Debugging enabled but some errors display exception "There has been a critical error on this website." without details

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am writing a custom plugin that uses a rest API to create WooCommerce products so I have enabled WP_DEBUG so that I can see the errors in my code. However certain errors that get triggered within WooCommerce Classes and WC Rest API stop the page without displaying the error, I even see the Notices and Warnings in my code, but when the page is aborted with a fatal error, it simply says:

```
There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.
```

My wp_config.php has all the settings:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG ', false );//tried with true too 
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY  ', true );
```

I've tried even right before my code setting

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

To give you an example I have the entire function with echos to pin point where the error in my code happens as is as below: [look at last 3 lines of function]

```
function create_product_variation( $product_id, $variation_data ){
     
     
    // Get the Variable product object (parent)
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

     // Iterating through the variations attributes
    foreach ($variation_data as $attributes  )
    {
         
        $variation_post = array(
            'post_title'  => $product->get_name().' '.$attributes['color'],
            'post_name'   => 'product-'.$product_id.'-variation',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_parent' => $product_id,
            'post_type'   => 'product_variation',
            'guid'        => $product->get_permalink()
        );       

        // Creating the product variation
        $variation_id = wp_insert_post( $variation_post );

        // Get an instance of the WC_Product_Variation object
        $variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );
         
         /* ####

         ####A LOT MORE CODE GOES INTO IT DOING MORE STUFF 

         #### */

        // Check if the post term exist and if not we set it in the parent variable product.
        if( ! in_array( $attributes['color'], $post_term_names ) )
            wp_set_post_terms( $product_id, $attributes['color'], $taxonomy, true );
        //echo " E-85 ".$variation_id."-".$taxonomy."-".$term_slug;
        // Set/save the attribute data in the product variation
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'attribute_'.$taxonomy, $term_slug );
     

        ## Set/save all other data

        // SKU
        //if( ! empty( $attributes['sku'] ) )
            //$variation->set_sku( $attributes['sku'] );
 
        // Prices
        if( empty( $attributes['sale_price'] ) ){
            $variation->set_price( $attributes['regular_price'] );
        } else {
            $variation->set_price( $attributes['sale_price'] );
            $variation->set_sale_price( $attributes['sale_price'] );
        }
         echo " E-103 ";//DISPLAYS STRING
        $variation->set_regular_price( $attributes['regular_price'] );
  
         
          echo " E-145 ";//DISPLAYS STRING
          $variation->save(); // Save the data - ERROR HAPPENS ON THIS LINE!!!
          echo " E-148 ";//DOES NOT DISPLAY  !!!!
    }
}
```

My best guess is that somehow WooCommerce errors are being handled with exception in the plugin? I also don't have any error or debugging plugins that might do anything like that.

Comment: Check the WooCommerce logs under WooCommerce >> Status >> Logs

Comment: If your function doesn't have any output to the screen then you can't echo an error.  Use the `error_log` for your output. Then look in your php error log or the debug.log if you enable it.